# How to obtain image from clipboard in a button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard

I'm trying to retrieve an image stored in the clipboard using jQuery. So far, I've managed to find a solution which works perfectly using the `onpaste` event. But, as per the requirements I want the same functionality in a "button click" instead of a "paste" event. I've tried to put the same code in a button click event, but with no luck. What am I missing here?

Here's my [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/harisni578/tb441u9r/12/)

If possible please tell me how I can do the same in IE(10 & above) & Mozilla Firefox.

Exapmle : [Demo Applet](http://supa.sourceforge.net/demo.php)

Comment: it's probably impossible - as this would be a major security hole (exactly the same as reading local files).

Answer (score 0):

As mozdev states, this feature should be available in FF since version 22.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/paste

"Caniuse" states that too btw: http://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard

Maybe you have to use a browser prefix or the event attributes have different names. Is your event not fired in other browser than chrome or is it fired but you don't receive data?

EDIT:
Additionally 'paste' is an event, you can't trigger it manually by a button. (Well you can but it doesn't make any difference.) This wouldn't make sense because you can't directly access the clipboard for security reasons and therefore you don't have the data available. in browser. With a button you have to use the file-select and upload method, which i think needs a webserver in the back to handle the request, so no pure js solution.

Comment: Event fired but not receiving data

Comment: Yes the you should tcheck the param names of your 'ev'-object. If the object doesn't contain data you don't have a chance. Otherwise you just have to use the other names for other browsers. (Or have a look at the specs of Webkit and IE)